# How to write a scala function which receives a map function to a generic type

Tags: scala, generics

Using Spark 1.3.0 with Scala, I have two functions which basically do the same on a given `RDD[(Long, String, Boolean, String)]`, up to a specifc map function from `(Long, String, Boolean, String)` to a tuple of 2 elements:

```
def rddToMap1(rdd: RDD[(Long, String, Boolean, String)]): Map[Long, Set[(String, Boolean)]] = {
rdd
  .map(t => (t._1, (t._2, t._3))) //mapping function 1
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.toSet)
  .collect
  .toMap
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
  .map(identity)
}


def rddToMap2(rdd: RDD[(Long, String, Boolean, String)]): Map[(Long, String), Set[String]] = {
rdd
  .map(t => ((t._1, t._2), t._4)) //mapping function 2
  .groupBy(_._1)
  .mapValues(_.toSet)
  .collect
  .toMap
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))
  .map(identity)
}
```

I want to write a generic function `genericRDDToMap` which I would later use to implement `rddToMap1` and `rddToMap2`.

This doesn't work:

```
def genericRDDToMap[A](rdd: RDD[(Long, String, Boolean, String)], mapFn: (Long, String, Boolean, String) => A) = {      
rdd     
  .map(mapFn) //ERROR       
  .groupBy(_._1)        
  .mapValues(_.toSet)       
  .collect      
  .toMap        
  .mapValues(_.map(_._2))       
  .map(identity)        
}
```

The (Eclipse) interpreter doesn't take `mapFn` as a valid mapping function, it says:

`type mismatch; found : (Long, String, Boolean, String) => A required: ((Long, String, Boolean, String)) => ?`

And even if I got over this, how would it know that my generic type `A` has value `_1` in the `groupBy` to follow?

To summarize: how do I do it right?

Answer (score 0):

You missed parentheses around `(Long, String, Boolean, String)`. And if `A` is of type *TupleX*, you can use upper bound to specify it (here I used `Tuple2`):

```
  def genericRDDToMap[X, Y, A <: Tuple2[X,Y]](rdd: RDD[(Long, String, Boolean, String)], 
                         mapFn: ((Long, String, Boolean, String)) => A) (implicit ev: ClassTag[A])= {     
      ... 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, but there's something missing in my case. when I use your header I get a `No ClassTag Available for A` error. When I add the `ClassTag`: `def genericRDDToMap[A <: Tuple2[_,_] : ClassTag]` it works out, but then when I implement `rddToMap1` I get a function which returns `Map[Any, Set[Any]]`:  `def rddToMap1(rdd: RDD[(Long, String, Boolean, String)]) = genericRDDToMap(rdd, mapFn = t => (t._1, (t._2, t._3)))`

Comment: try to specify `Tuple2` type params, Answer was updated.